# SQL query for pivot table

Tags: mysql

I have table with two columns, Name and countries visited:

```
Name   Subjects
mike   england
maria  china
james  russia
mike   mexico
maria  france
laurel england
...    ...
```

Now I want to write a query which will display the number of people who visited two countries, three, four and so on up to ten.

The final result should look like:

```
Number of countries -> number of people
10                  -> 5
9                   -> 13
8                   -> 24
and so on.
```

So how do I proceed with this?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following schema for you table (I named it subjects and the id column was added for the sake of unique key)

```
CREATE TABLE `subjects` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

following query can achieve your desired result

```
SELECT a.c AS num_of_countries, COUNT(*) AS num_of_people 
FROM 
    (SELECT `country`, COUNT(*) AS c FROM subjects GROUP BY 1) a 
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: I guess you got my question wrong. your solution display just considers the with respect to country but not the ppl. Please check and again

Comment: what I understood was that you want the number of countries listed in one column with number of people who have visited that much countries in the next column i.e. according to the data in your question following results will be displayed: 1->2 & 4->1. i.e. there is one country which has been visited by 2 people and there are four countries visited by 1 person

Comment: I've updated the query and now getting the desired result, please check again

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT t2.number_of_country, 
       count(t1.Name) number_of_people
FROM tableName t1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Name, count(Subjects) number_of_country
     FROM tableName 
     GROUP BY Name) t2 ON t2.Name = t1.Name
GROUP BY t2.number_of_country
```

Comment: Can you be little specific about the scheme you considered for the above query?

Comment: You have to see the query as 2 subqueries. The first one in the inner join give the number of country by people. In your example it will return Mike -> 2, Maria -> 2, james -> 1. Then you use this subresult to get the number of people with the same number of country.